# PHP MySQL -> Joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables, movie and booking. The movie table looks like, with two directors 1 and 2 from director table:

ID    | movie      | director      | status
1      | movie1    | 1                | 1
2      | movie2    | 1                | 1
3      | movie3    | 2                | 1
4      | movie4    | 2                | 1

The booking table looks like:

ID   | Userid    |   startdatetime          | duration       | enddatetime          | movie_id       | status
5     | 4          | 1429058640         | 3                  | 1429059480             | 2                         | 1
6     | 7          | 1429058640         | 3                  | 1429059480             | 4                         | 0
9     | 4          | 1429058640         | 3                  | 1429059480             | 3                         | 1

What I am trying to do (search query) :

Variable that am getting are : 
director_id = 1,
 datetime = 1429056840
 Userid = 4 and
 duration = 3

If user search for director from movie table of id 1. First, it checks for the datetime, if it comes between startdatetime and enddatetime will suggest other movie's of director, here its director with id 1 from movie table.
And if datetime comes before startdatetime or after  enddatetime than it will show only one random movie from director with id 1.

query I am trying :

```
SELECT v.ID AS id 
FROM movie v, booking b 
WHERE v.director =1 
AND v.status =1 
AND b.status=1 
AND b.movie_id = v.ID 
AND b.Userid =  '4' 
AND ( 1429056600 > b.startdatetime OR 1429056600 < b.enddatetime )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Cannot understand what you need?

Comment: hope, now its little cleared

Comment: Hi it's a little confusing what you want to do exactly... look at [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88396/5) and check if i'm on the right way to solve your problem... P.S. i add some new rows in booking so don't be confused...

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic : sorry for late reply, i want opposite of it, if datetime is between startdatetime and enddatetime, means the movie is booked, so i want to show other movie_id from same director. Thanks for the the help.

Comment: No problem, try something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32336/1) i have to add few more data in movies table. There is a few things i don't understand about query and what you value you get to work with etc... but I hope we're on the right track :) NOTE: don't be confused if you run query few times and get same result's because it's have only three values which he can randomly choose so just execute few times and selected number will change

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic :thanks i thnk it will work :) and thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that i could help.. I'll post it later as answer so you can mark it as useful. :) GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion in comment we come with this solution for the problem:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM movies
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(m.ID)
                 FROM movies m
                 INNER JOIN booking b
                 ON m.ID = b.movie_id
                 WHERE m.director = 1 AND b.Userid = 4 AND b.duration = 3 AND
                        1429058640 BETWEEN b.startdatetime AND b.enddatetime)
AND director = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Here is [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32336/1) so you can see how it's work...

Also if you have any further question about this query fill free to ask, i will do my best to tray to explain you and to adapt the query if needed...

GL!